# SN75176A in full duplex application

Tags: rs485

I am trying to interface with an RS485 device (laser) that is full duplex (115.2k).

I am using two SN75176A ics... I can receive data from the laser fine, but I can't transmit any data to the laser.

Looking at one side of the  differential outputs of the SN75176A it looks like the nothing is coming through, the output is just hovering above 1V, but the input side looks ok.

The schematic I am using is attached.  The top SN75176A is RX into the micro and works OK.

Anything wrong with the circuit to transmit data from the micro?

[image]

Attached is a scope shot, channel 4 is input, channel 7 is output

[image]

Comment: What's the laser device - link to data sheet please

Comment: @Daves "To the laser" What laser? There is no mention of a laser in the post except for that sentance

Comment: Is it a full-duplex device? Probably no. Likely can combine RX & TX and use one SN75176 and toggle RE+DE to receive/transmit. Research the differences between RS232, RS422, and RS485. What "485" parameters is it expecting? Parity bit?

Comment: Be explicit for your probe signals input and output. Is the output the feedback of inverted Rx while Tx laser turns on and only gets a glitch?  If so validate all intermediate signals.

Comment: recheck VCC and DE on the RS485 driver.

Comment: I'll double check Vcc and DE. They are being powered from the same bus as other things that are working OK, but maybe the wires fell off.  I can link to the data sheet for the laser, but it shouldn't matter what is on the other end if the communication protocol parameters are correct, which they are because I am receiving data OK.  @rdtsc Is it a full duplex device? Definitely yes.....

Comment: https://www.micro-epsilon.com/download/products/cat-optoncdt/dax--optoNCDT-1420--en-us.html#page=2&zoom=Fit

Comment: Hmm the datasheet says "RS422" not "RS485"...

Comment: So I miss typed...but the questions remains the same... the chip can handle RS422... that's why I have one for rx and one for tx